# How to implement a leaderboard in libgdx - player name and scores

Tags: java, libgdx, desktop, preferences, leaderboard

I am creating a game and I'm trying to create a leaderboard. Before hand, on my game over screen, I made it so that the high score across all plays would be shown. 
Now I am trying to create a leaderboard instead which has the username and the score both on it. 
I want to use Preferences to do so.

I originally tried to get the username by creating a method which gets a username. But then I tried to combine this with the score that user would get but it would not work.

```
if (Score > highscore) {
        prefs.putInteger ("highscore", Score);
        prefs.flush();
    }
```

This is my code for the highscore - how would I change my code though, so that I can get both a username where their highscore is attached to it.

Comment: you need send Score data to server then in the leaderboard page get best player by score to show

Comment: Can I not use preferences to store the data and then fetch it from there in the leaderboard class?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want to do i think it's easier to just have a Util class that serialize / deserialize an object to the local files folder, i will give you an example, you must adapt it to work with a list of scores, i will leave that to you.

```
public class SaveUtils {
    private static Json serializer = new Json();

    public static ScoreObject loadScore(){
        FileHandle fhp = Gdx.files.local("saves/score.json");
        if(fhp.exists()){
            String scoreStr = fhp.readString();
            ScoreObject score= serializer.fromJson(ScoreObject.class,scoreStr );
            return score;
        }
        return new ScoreObject();
    }

    public static void scoreSave(ScoreObject score) {
        String scoreStr = serializer.toJson(score.getConfig());
        FileHandle fhp = Gdx.files.local("saves/score.json");
        fhp.writeString(scoreStr ,false,"UTF-8");
    }
}
```